# Ubuntu 20.04 kernel 5.11 drivers for Intel I225-V LAN & 6E AX210 PCIE WiFi

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, kernel, iwlwifi

My ubuntu is offline so can't do with any updates. I tried updating kernel offline but it didn't work. Do we have Intel I225-V LAN & 6E AX210 PCIE WiFi drivers which I can install offline?

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `sudo modprobe -v iwlwifi && sudo dmesg | grep iwl` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score -1):

I upgraded to 5.16 and it was fixed. I think both of these are not supported in 5.11 kernel.

Anyone reading this don't waste your time and just upgrade to 5.16 or latest kernel to fix the issue.

Comment: They are both supported in 5.11. You had another undiagnosed issue. In any case, we're glad it's now working.

Comment: Yes, I know they are supported in 5.11, it is working on my other PC. I just couldn't figure it out why it is not working on the new PC. Wasted 2 full day.